# Help removing rtl tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl) tag is defined as Register-transfer-level in its wiki. This only makes sense for questions related to an [hdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdl) such as [verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/verilog) or [vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vhdl). I retagged some questions with [right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/right-to-left) but there are others that appear to be related to run-time-library, which has no tag. I started to delete the tag from these questions, but now my edits are getting rejected as being too minor.

Can someone do a mass edit to remove this tag from these run-time-library questions? Or create a tag for that and retag?

Answer (score 6):

Not really an answer, but this got too long for a comment...

Your suggested edit comment (I just looked at [one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4245761), which was just "removed rtl tag") could certainly be a cause of why these edits were / are being rejected. A more correct reject reason may actually be "invalid edit", "radical change" or "vandalism" (although I personally tend to take a closer look than most, and may approve because I would've looked what the tag says and what the question is about), since it's not at all clear why you're just removing the tag.

You need to use the comment to motivate your edit - don't just explain what you did, it's mostly easy enough to see that. Write something like "I removed the rtl tag because this question is about run-time libraries, but the rtl tag is about register-transfer-level".

Some edits are still going to get rejected, but that's just how things go sometimes. I'd personally recommend (perhaps somewhat controversially) waiting until you have 2k reputation so your edits don't need to be approved before doing too much site maintenance  - perhaps try to focus on other ways to improve the site (not sure what...) (although more people who work to improve the site, however they see fit, assuming it's actually improving the site, isn't really a bad thing, so take the advice with a pinch of salt). Once you've gotten there, you should also generally have a better understanding of what's appropriate and what isn't (not that I'm saying there's anything wrong with your knowledge of Stack Overflow - but there's always more to learn).

In general, I don't think you should just be removing a tag in scenario's like this (without replacing it with another tag) without careful consideration and (perhaps somewhat controversially) believe that no edit might be better in some / most cases because just removing it severs any link to run-time-libraries, even if that leaves the rtl tag messy - I'd suggest rather posting a Meta discussion about the messy rtl tag and let the more experienced users deal with it. Just something to keep in mind. It takes a lot of experience to know when a tag would be useful and when it wouldn't, and I certainly don't claim to have sufficient experience to be giving advice here, just enough for the occasional burnination request and new tag removal.

Comment: Once I had the edit rejected I came here to figure out what to do and quickly realized that I was handling this incorrectly. Should have left the tags alone and posted to meta from the beginning. Now I know!

Answer (score 5):

I believe I removed the tag [rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl) from questions that shouldn't have that tag. If I missed one feel free to leave a comment.

A handfull of those question where refering to the RTL of [delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi). I couldn't find a good retag target. I assume [vcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcl) would be wrong. For now I removed those tags. If there is a need for a tag like [delphi-rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-rtl), feel free to create one.

Comment: created [tag:delphi-rtl] for that. The docs seemed to point to http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_the_RTL_(Run-Time_Library), so named it [delphi-run-time-library].

Answer (score 1):

This is still an issue. From time to time, I review the questions tagged with [rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl), and replace it with [right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/right-to-left) where applicable. At the time of writing this, there are 75 questions tagged with [rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl) and 1,017 questions tagged with [right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/right-to-left). One could argue register-transfer-level should give-up the ownership of [rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl) and give it to the more popular right-to-left. I (someone who has earned almost all his rep from HDL related tags) would prefer to find a more holistic solution that keep the RTL tag (or a least a form of it) with HDL and can work nicely with the right-to-left and run-time-library tags.

- One possible long-term solution is to improve the suggested tags. Only suggest [rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl) when there is a related [hdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdl) tags / suggested-tags; such as [verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/verilog), [vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vhdl), [system-verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system-verilog), [fpga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fpga), [asic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asic), etc. Otherwise it can suggest [right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/right-to-left) or perhase additional rules of when to suggest run-time-library related tags. I don't know how feasible or piratical it is to do this. I can imagine performance degradation if more tags create rules like this for suggested tags.
- Another option is to rename [rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl) to something more meaningful (ex: [hdl-rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdl-rtl)) then burnination [rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl) so no can bring it back. Maybe create [layout-rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layout-rtl) as a synonym to [right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/right-to-left).

I'm sure the are holes in these suggestions, but hopefully there is enough to inspire collaboration and productive action.

Comment: renamed it as [tag:register-transfer-level]. Should solve most of the issues.