# Should the synonym "RTL" be moved from register-transfer-level to right-to-left?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

It is basically a 6-year-old problem on Stack Overflow. See this topic:
*[Help removing rtl tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250964/help-removing-rtl-tag)*

Where it seems there is a constant fight to tag the questions correctly, and even now you can find questions tagged with [register-transfer-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/register-transfer-level) instead of the correct [rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl) tag.

As you can see here: *[Questions tagged [register-transfer-level]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/register-transfer-level)*

Of the first 10 questions, six of them belong to the [right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/right-to-left) tag.

I became aware of this issue with this question which was tagged incorrectly and fixed:
*[How to change direction of text to rtl by aspose.diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67481517)*

I personally believe that the majority of developers will think about [right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/right-to-left) when reading the tag [rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl) and there I would suggest to make the change.

**Edit:**

Sooo, 7 days have passed since the last activity, is this problem solvable or do we postpone it for another 6 years?

Comment: Seems to be a byproduct of renaming the [rtl] tag to [register-transfer-level], looks like some noob mod handled the other 6 year old question. Honestly, I'd rather delete [tag:rtl] completely, but it would just end up getting recreated, so the best option remaining is to move it to [right-to-left].

Comment: @BhargavRao Why no delete rtl and blacklist it

Comment: @Nick blacklist needs dev approval, and without a strong reason, it won't get any. (note: blacklist is a heavy operation)

Comment: ... Well that's annoying

Comment: I wouldn't think about *anything* specific, programming related when reading "rtl". Such a TLA is practically meaningless without context. Just remove the synonym and write it out...

Comment: Yes, yes it should.

Comment: It is surprisingly difficult to get Google to return right-to-left for the search term rtl alone, or if you use vacuous terms like "programming", "code", "developer" or even "design". You have to ask it something like rtl direction, rtl layout, rtl script or rtl writing before it'll guess right-to-left. No wonder some people think rtl stands for "register transfer level". I think it really depends on what group of people you ask. The vast majority of UI/web/game developers, as well as writers (technical or not) will tell you it means right-to-left, even absent of context.

Comment: The question then becomes whether "rtl" is ambiguous enough to warrant not allowing its use as a tag, synonym or otherwise. Personally I'd be surprised if it was. But, you know, I'm not a digital designer. I could be biased.

Comment: is removing the abbreviation as synonym and adding the abbreviation to the tag it self `register-transfer-level [RTL]` and `right-to-left [RTL]` an option? this way users typing rtl, in the list of tags, should get both tags and hopefully pick the correct one.

Comment: @RandRandom That would be too verbose in my opinion. We'd just want to refer to the acronym in the tag wiki excerpt. Of course, everyone reads those...

Comment: Ironically, when I read the title of this question, I was very confused, because I thought, *clearly* everybody knows that RTL stands for *register transfer language*, a class of internal compiler representations used, among others, in GCC and CompCert.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Yeah, same, another vote here for reading RTL as Register Transfer Language; I never come across RTL in my day-to-day usage, but certainly do think about GCC internals. But I don't expect my experience to be typical.  So similar to letting [more popular non-assembly usage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399396) of `[gas]` take that away from the `[gnu-assembler]`, looks like it's time to give this one up.  (unlike [gas], I've never wanted to tag a question [rtl], and the [gcc] tag covers GCC's flavour of it if we do have questions about RTL)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Oddly, I expected your link to go to a page explaining Ethereum … I know about GNU Assembler, of course, but my second association would be the Ethereum meaning. I never heard of Google Apps Script until now.

Comment: ? RTL > Radio Télévision Luxembourg > https://www.rtl.de :-D

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks RTL stands for run-time library?

Comment: I thought of [RTL/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTL/2) a language based on ALGOL 68.

Answer (score 15):

I agree; I think it's wrong to synonymize [rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl) to [register-transfer-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/register-transfer-level). [rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl) should have been synonymized to [right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/right-to-left) because when someone reads "RTL" they almost surely will think "Right to Left" rather than "Register Transfer Level".

There are currently 177 questions with [register-transfer-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/register-transfer-level). By my count there are currently 23 questions tagged [register-transfer-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/register-transfer-level) that used [rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl) to mean "Right to Left"... they're all currently on the [first page of the tag filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/register-transfer-level), or in other words, they've all been asked in the last year.

Comment: *when someone reads "RTL" they almost surely will think "Right to Left" rather than "Register Transfer Level".* Um, this seems to be wholly dependent on whether your background has more to do with text rendering or hardware design. Admittedly, the former is probably more common, so I can't really argue with that logic (no pun intended), but as a member of the supposed minority, I'd much prefer simply deleting [tag:rtl] than synonymizing it to the more popular thing, which is likely to just make the obscure meaning even more obscure.

Comment: @trentcl I think the downside of deleting the tag is that we simply delay the inevitable date it comes back, instead of dealing with the problem in a way that will hopefully be somewhat clearer to more folks than it is now.

Comment: @trentcl Sure, if someone is using Verilog/VHDL, they may think of Register Transfer Level first. But the number of people who deal with text direction massively outnumbers those who use Verilog/VHDL. ~11,000 questions in those two tags vs over 55,000 results for the search term "text-direction", and over *440,000* results for the search term "right-to-left". Don't fall prey to an epistemic bubble!

Comment: @trentcl Regarding if someone types in RTL and lands on results of people trying to get Arabic text to display correctly on their webpage, do you think people are searching for Register Transfer Level information by using the keyword RTL? And that they would lose out if not able to search for it based on the keyword RTL? I doubt it... they would search for Register Transfer Level instead and only *then* learn it is abbreviated often as RTL. We *could* add a [tag:hardware-RTL] tag or something to help, I suppose.

Comment: I *absolutely do* think people are searching for information about register transfer level code using the RTL abbreviation, as pointed out in the question comments, that is by far the most common search hit for the abbreviation *outside of Stack Overflow*. The epistemic bubble here is *Stack Overflow itself*, which strongly suggests that re-synonymizing [tag:rtl] will not discourage people from using it incorrectly.

Comment: @trentcl I disagree; Stack Overflow isn't a bubble here, but a much larger field. Otherwise the term ''bubble" wouldn't make any sense. I don't think a user would learn about "RTL" without first learning it stands for "Register Transfer Level". At the very least they probably look up the term before needing to ask/search for a programming-related question about it here.

Comment: You seem to be saying that people learn about abbreviations by searching for the expanded form, which... doesn't make sense to me. Did you learn the abbreviation "CSS" by searching for "Cascading Style Sheets"? Or did you come across the acronym first and only then learn what it stood for? I'm confused how this argument is supposed to favor "right-to-left" which if anything is an even more obvious, searchable acronym than "register transfer level" which is jargon of which the acronym has a life of its own.

Comment: @trentcl: I learned the abbreviation [CSS](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Scramble_System) from one of the few [software-related court cases](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Lech_Johansen#DeCSS_prosecution) that received widespread mainstream media attention.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: Oddly, I learned about DeCSS just a couple of years after learning Cascading Style Sheets, when reading about similar cases.

Comment: @trentcl No, I'm saying they would not be searching for *programming questions on Stack Overflow* by using the term "RTL" unless they already knew it stood for "Register Transfer Level".

Comment: This makes no sense at all. If I know how to deal with right-to-left on CSS, I won't know about C++, .net, java, etc. Only the people that know those will be able to answer those questions. Right to left is domain specific to each language/framework/context/etc. It should not exist as tag.

Comment: I don't understand how people are even arguing about this. Right-to-left is a **human language** term and the acronym RTL is long-established for referring to it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_script. It's relevant to computers, and therefore Stack Overflow, because they often deal with the presentation of human languages; but to claim that the acronym RTL is "more relevant" to a particular field of computing than to human language, is an "argument" so weak it may as well not exist.

Comment: @IanKemp that's not enough to deserve a tag. That's why.

Comment: @Braiam Oh, I completely agree that we don't need an `rtl` tag, the problem is that unless we get it blacklisted (which seems to be an inordinately difficult process) it will just come back and be abused by whatever particularly entitled group thinks it belongs to them. So pragmatically, if blacklisting isn't possible, the most logical thing to do is synonymize it to `right-to-left`.

Comment: @IanKemp well, technically a moderator just have to merge the tag and remove the synonym and then hope for people to not recreate it (and if it does, remove it fast).

Comment: @TylerH "[People] would not be searching ... Stack Overflow by using the term 'RTL' unless they already knew it stood for 'Register Transfer Level'" I disagree. In my engineering classes, "RTL" was the term used, not "Register Transfer Level". It was mentioned once, but I quickly forgot it because everyone says "RTL". In fact, my first thought from "RTL" is "resistor-transistor logic". The point is that it is reasonable to search for RTL and expect "Register Transfer Level". Perhaps "RTL = right-to-left" with a mention in the tag summary would be sufficient (a "did you mean").

Answer (score 10):

No, it should not be re-synonymized. It should just be deleted, since it is ambiguous.

The acronym "RTL" is well-established on the Internet at large in the "register transfer level" sense, as shown by a search result for "RTL" on your favorite non-tracking search engine. The dominance of this meaning outside of Stack Overflow strongly implies that re-synonymizing it will not discourage casual SO users (who have encountered the acronym elsewhere) from using it in the (newly) incorrect sense when they have programming-related questions. Admittedly, that's still probably *less* bad than the current situation, since the overlap between RTL hardware design and programming is smaller than the overlap between text processing and programming; however, it's still not great because it invites the same problem albeit on a smaller scale.

Ideally, the ambiguous acronym would also be blocked, but apparently that's hard to do. The next best thing is probably creating synonyms that will appear as suggestions when a user types "rtl" into the tag field. I think [rtl-logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl-logic) makes the most sense for [register-transfer-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/register-transfer-level). As for [right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/right-to-left), maybe [rtl-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl-text).

If people persist in creating questions erroneously tagged [rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl), it would be fair at that point to inventory those questions and make an argument for whether it should be blacklisted or synonymized to [right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/right-to-left). Re-synonymizing it at this point strikes me as premature.

Comment: RTL also stands for Register Transfer Language (in compiler internals), although we don't need a tag for that meaning; GCC's version of it (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/RTL.html) is covered by [gcc], and for people inventing their own or working on other compilers there's [compiler-construction].  We should have an rtl tag that's synonymized to something, just so a new [rtl] tag doesn't get created.  (blacklists are overkill, and apparently inconvenient?).  At least having useful auto-completes pop up for rtl would be good, too.

Comment: “The acronym "RTL" is well-established on the Internet at large in the "register transfer level" sense, as shown by a search result for "RTL" on your favorite non-tracking search engine.” — *How exactly* did you establish that? Because when I search for RTL most of what I find obviously refers to other things, and I can’t discern a clear preference for “register-transfer level” over “right-to-left”. (That said, I agree with the deletion.)

Comment: @Konrad Fair enough, I deliberately skipped over company names that have nothing obvious to do with programming, but in every case I tried "register transfer level" was the dominant acronym ignoring those.

Comment: Side note: I considered also using Google Ngrams, but, while I could find plenty of hardware-specific phrases ("RTL logic", "RTL circuit", "RTL code") I couldn't actually find a *single* phrase that would be specific to the "right-to-left" phrasing ("RTL script" and "RTL text" have too few hits to register, and "RTL language" is ambiguous).

Comment: @KonradRudolph if you use google, it interprets that you are looking at stuff related to c++, .net, etc. . If you have a background on hardware, then it shows you the other meaning. If you are in the finance business, it shows you RTL group.

Comment: @Braiam … I obviously used the private browsing mode to get an unbiased search listing.

Comment: Although I agree with the deletion, I don’t think _RTL_ meaning “_Register Transfer level_” is well-established on the Internet. [A Google search for "right to left"](https://www.google.com/search?q="right+to+left") returns more than 43 million results. ["Register transfer level"](https://www.google.com/search?q="register+transfer+level") returns 256 000 results. Surely the people who discuss the former also use the _RTL_ abbreviation. Now, of course, these results are not restricted to programming.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you really believe that's enough? You country, what google knows about you, etc. influences. The only way you can get biased towards someone else results. Try bing or duckduckgo and you will see [that right to left is not even in the first 3 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLWkZ.png)

Comment: @Braiam When using private browsing “what Google knows about you” does *not* influence search results. Your location does but that isn’t terribly relevant here. — And in fact, searching for `rtl "right-to-left"` yields vastly more results than does `rtl "register-transfer level`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph seems that you have a serious misunderstanding of what google does. [Here, google with private](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaJ4M.png) and [without](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14QTR.png). Notice the uncanny resemblance? Try it. Also, amount of results doens't matter for SO.

Comment: @Braiam I can assure you I don’t, and I get *completely* different results with and without private browsing mode. If you don’t, might I suggest that you either don’t usually use Google, or that you’re now using it wrong? At any rate, my results are not at all dependent on Google.

Comment: @KonradRudolph well, your results are all dependent of contextual information, which is the point. Google isn't representative of every user of SO. Also, this is my work device, which would say that I use google right :D

Comment: I think that rtl-order would make more sense than rtl-text, but even better:  rtl-right-to-left and rtl-register-transfer-level.  Those would be stupid tags, but they make more sense as synonyms than things like rtl-logic.  I mean, how would someone know that rtl-logic does not refer to right-to-left-logic?  Whereas those who type rtl and see rtl-right-to-left and rtl-register-transfer-level would immediately know which of the two they wanted.

Comment: I think mdfst (@randrandom)'s solution (rtl-right-to-left and rtl-register-transfer-level) which is similar to what I see Wiki's doing is correct.  If you type an ambiguous term into most Wiki's, it takes you to a disambiguation page.  As far as I can tell, that's the effect that is wanted here.  And the argument that rtl-xxxxx is too verbose is ignoring the ambiguity.  When I use a tag, I'm hoping to draw the appropriate attention to my question.  I am hoping to disambiguate what my question is about....

Answer (score -9):

In 2 years rtl got 109 renames, that means 55 a year or ~4.5 month. Right to left gets 4 question last 30 days. That would mean that there are far more right to left questions than register transfer level, right? Well, yes, but here's the thing: right to left top answerers have only 1 answer. The two with most answers are because they answer css or android/c++/java questions, all of these tags represent a sizeable chunk tags related to right-to-left. The existence of a right-to-left tag is suspect at best.

So here's a spitball idea: what if we remove the synonym of rtl to any tag and the right to left tag. Register transfer level question won't have to deal with the stray right-to-left tagged question and we don't have to decide which the TLA tag synonym has to point to.

Comment: You need *some* kind of tag to indicate when someone wants to change the text direction for a document/page. The question is too common to not have one. The subject is not well-curated, for sure, but I suspect if it were the top answerers would have more than 1 answer.

Comment: @TylerH no, you don't need a tag, you need a title. Titles are the description of the problem, the elevator pitch. Tags aren't meant to describe the problem, they aren't #hashtags.

Comment: Tags are classifications (which are also what hashtags are for, btw)

Comment: @TylerH no, hashtags are a buzzword for social ittreactions around nebulous topics. Tags are for answerers to find questions to answer. We aren't a library to implement a Dewey Decimal system.

Comment: Erm... no, hashtags serve a purpose that is identical to Stack Overflow tags.